# Any() the result of the expression is always "false"

Tags: c#, list

After ready the documentation about the any() function of the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)

Any() is supposed to return true if it find the object matching a condition

I have a list of article and before to add an article in the list I want to check if this article is already in my list.

```
foreach (Article a in _lstArticleTemp)
{
    if (_lstMarqueTemp.Any(item => item == a.Marque))
        _lstMarqueTemp.Add(a.Marque);
}
```

But it saying : the result of the expression is always "false" since a value of type int is never equal to null of type int?

[image]

Comment: _Where_ do you get that error?

Comment: Is `a.Marque` or `item` is nullable?

Comment: Marque containt an int? Id and a String name

Comment: OK, show us how is `_lstMarqueTemp` declared, and how does `Article` class look like.

Comment: One is an int and one is a nullable int. Hence the `int?` type.  You are comparing two different things here. If you know Marque is always non-null you can check on `a.Marquee.Value` (or `item.Value`, depending on which thing is the `int?`) but that's dangerous since its obviously nullable.

Comment: @Seb: int? is a so-called Nullable type, documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx. You will need to make use of the `HasValue` and `Value` members of the Nullable type.

Comment: _lstMarqueTemp is a List of Marque (List<Marque>)

Comment: @devshorts But the `==` operator ought to be lifted for nullable comparisons.  `new int() == new int?()` compiles just fine, no warning.

Comment: @Servy the warning is from resharper, and you do get an "expression is always false warning" there.

Comment: @elgonzo That is false.  `int` and `Nullable` are both value types, not reference types.  The `==` operator is not comparing their references, unless they're being boxed due to code not shown.

Comment: @Servy: You are right. Bummer... i will delete my 'stupid' comment. Sorry... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is improper.  There is nothing wrong with that code; it will function properly because the `==` operator for `int` (and all other value types) is lifted to support nullable values.

Comment: you are right and after recompilier the solution, the warning was not there anymore